# Opening Heroku | Page not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following [this tutorial](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app) to a tee and so far so good. I ran into a problem on step 2.6

On my terminal I input

```
 heroku open
```

After which it opened a new webpage on Chrome.

The terminal then displayed

```
 Opening aqueous-forest-3891... done
```

The webpage that opened was https://aqueous-forest-3891.herokuapp.com/ and unfortunately it says the webpage may have been moved or does not exist.

I've followed the tutorial exactly (as far as I can tell) and can't figure out what I've done wrong. I'm **very** new to Rails (and Ruby....and Heroku...).

I'm not exactly sure how to troubleshoot my problem or if there's a command I can use in my terminal for debugging - etc.

Comment: Make sure that you've run `git push heroku master`. if you did successfully, then run this `heroku logs -n 1500` and refresh the page to see if you can figure out something form the log. If you don't, post it here.

Answer (score 3):

Good news: a *Rails error* means your app is running on the server

Bad news : your routes are likely causing a problem.

According to [this blog](http://hacktivist.in/articles/Rails/) (which has exactly the same issue), the problem is that Heroku won't host the "default" Rails page. You'll need to create a default page & redeploy:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index"

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
Hello world

$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Default Page"
$ git push heroku master
```

---

**Context**

The error you're seeing is one from Rails:

[image]

This is good, as it means your Rails app is actually on the Heroku server & being picked up. This type of error is either suggestive that you have an error with your server (`500` error), or a missing page (`404` error).

-

If you had the following error, it would be a Heroku (platform) centric issue:

[image]

This is normally caused either by a lack of database connectivity, or some sort of environment issue (`ENV` vars missing etc).

---

The best way to debug Heroku is to use the Heroku logs.

These are written - as with most event-based software - on the server, allowing you to see what's going on. Heroku recently upgraded their software to include a [new real-time logging system](https://twitter.com/heroku/status/669681968041226240):

[image]

Checking in there will tell you what's going on, allowing you to take direct action to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your issue you will need to view the logs. A quick way is to add the Papertrail add on to your app (there's a free option). Add-ons can be added via the resources tab from Heroku.

Another option is to to view the heroku logs in the terminal with the command

```
heroku logs -t --app appName
```

By viewing the logs, you should get some error messages that will help you debug why your app isn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deployed custom branch to heroku master, which; heroku usually does not build itself. 
If you want to deploy custom branch to heroku use this command.

`git push -f heroku your_branch_name:master`